# Sql-Clr Security Exception

Tags: security, sql-server-2008, exception, sqlclr

Recently i created an application which could get the password of the user, whose username is provided as the parameter, i checked the code, its working fine, now i created a class library so that i can add this assemnbly in sql server 2008, below is the code of my class library.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Security;

public class DnnUserCredentials
{
    public static string GetUserPassword(string username)
    {
        MembershipUser objUser = Membership.GetUser(username);
        return objUser.GetPassword();
    }
}
```

i created the assembly in sql server 2008 like below

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY DNN_USER_CREDENTIALS FROM 'E:\NBM SITES\SqlProjectDll (DO NOT DELETE)\UserCredentials.dll' WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
```

i got the command completed successfully message, then i created a function like below:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_UserCredentials](@UserName [nvarchar](max))
RETURNS [nvarchar](max) WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [DNN_USER_CREDENTIALS].[DnnUserCredentials].[GetUserPassword]
```

here too i got the command completed successfully message, now when i tried to call the function using

```
SELECT [dbo].[fn_UserCredentials]('host')
```

it throws me below error:

```
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "fn_UserCredentials": 
System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
System.Security.SecurityException: 
   at DnnUserCredentials.GetUserPassword(String username)
```

any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what can be the problem. First try to change the PERMISSION_SET to Unrestricted.
When this does not help try to debug the DLL from visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set [PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345101.aspx) to get access to remote resources.
Also you might want to set [TRUSTWORTHY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx) flag to ON.

```
ALTER [<DBName>] SET TRUSTWORTHY ON
GO
CREATE ASSEMBLY [<assemblyName>]
--user with sysadmin rights for this DB may be required for deploing
AUTHORIZATION [<someSysadmin>]
FROM '[<pathToDll>]'
--compiled with unsafe to access EventLog for example
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
GO
```